# SQL SELF JOIN eliminate duplicated values

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have to select distinct month ID the below query is returning duplicated values. How to fix this ?

```
 SELECT DISTINCT m1.ID as C1, m2.ID as C2
    FROM Mois m1, Mois m2
    WHERE m1.ID IN('1','4','9')
    AND m2.ID IN('2','5','10')
```

[image]

This is what i want to get :

```
C1 |  C2 

1  |  2

4  |  5

9  |  10
```

Comment: what is your expected output and also sample data.

Comment: There are no duplicates, at least not with regard to _both_ ID columns.  What is your expected output?

Comment: You need to have a method of aggregating these duplicates (c1=1,c2=2) is different to (c1=1,c2=3)

Comment: How to chose c2 value for the c1 value?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I want that each column contains distinct values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this option:

```
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT m1.ID as C1, m2.ID as C2
    FROM Mois m1
    INNER JOIN Mois m2
    ON m1.ID IN (1, 4, 9) AND
       m2.ID IN (2, 5, 10) AND
       m1.ID < m2.ID
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT C1, C2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY C1 ORDER BY C2) rn
    FROM cte1
)

SELECT C1, C2
FROM cte2
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY C1;

C1   C2
1   1   2
2   4   5
3   9   10
```

### Demo

Comment: What a nice Query ! Thank you !!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MIN(C1),MIN(C2) FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT m1.ID as C1, m2.ID as C2,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY m2.ID ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS ROWNUM
    FROM Mois m1
    INNER JOIN Mois m2
    ON m1.ID IN (1, 4, 9) AND
       m2.ID IN (2, 5, 10) AND
       m1.ID < m2.ID
) AS T1
GROUP BY ROWNUM
```

OR

```
SELECT C1,C2 from
(SELECT DISTINCT m1.ID AS C1, 
    Row_number() over (Order by (SELECT 0)) AS RN
    FROM Mois m1
    WHERE m1.ID IN('1','4','9')) AS T1
INNER JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT m2.ID AS C2,
    Row_number() over (Order by (SELECT 0)) AS RN
    FROM  Mois m2
    WHERE m2.ID IN('2','5','10')) AS T2
 ON T1.RN=T2.RN
```

Output

```
C1  C2
1   2
4   5
9   10
```

Demo

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f64e5/2

Comment: That depends on your definition of the word "better" :-)